# PHP Toolkit / Easycom giving iSeries message

Tags: php, zend-framework, ibm-midrange, toolkit, zend-server

We have PHP with Zend Server, running on an iSeries.

Our iSeries is v6r1m1.
Our Zend Server is version 5.6.0.
Our PHP version is 5.2.17.

When using the i5_Connection and i5_Program from our PHP Toolkit classes, the following message is displayed in our operator messages, and requires an “I” for the response answer.
**EASYCOM for PHP - The PHP Toolkit for IBM i - For Support and Updates,
   Free Registration at : http://www.easycom-aura.com (I)**

What exactly do we need to do to stop getting this message?

I see on the website listed in the message there is this:
**Easycom For PHP, Evaluation

Native access to iSeries - AS/400 databases and programs from internet applications.
Easycom For PHP compatible with PHP 4 and 5**

However, it says “Evaluation”.  Will this only work for a period of time? Will we then need to purchase something?

If anyone is familiar with this, i would appreicate any help or advice.

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outside of a vendor provided solution you can have the system auto reply to the message.

1. Determine the message id of the reply message being generated.
2. Use the `WRKRPYLE` command to determine an unused reply list entry sequence number.
3. Use the `ADDRPYLE SEQNBR(?) MSGID(?) RPY(I)` command to add a default reply.  Replace `?` with the appropriate sequence number and message id.

Note that if the message id is a generic message such as `CPF9898` you can add comparison data to make sure to only answer this specific message.  For example: `CMPDTA(EASYCOM 1)`.

Comment: will this prevent the message from showing up in the operator messages?  if it still shows up, we will have thousands of these every day, which would flood out other important messages =P

Comment: @adam I'm not aware of a way to block the messages entirely.  There is a link for a price request on the vendor website so it doesn't appear to be a free product.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  We are now looking into a stored proc that will call the RPG program... as the contract with this company doesnt seam too appealing at this time.